# How to ignore conflicts in tortoiseSVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2008, tortoisesvn

I am working on a `Visual Studio` project and I know that I can ignore when conflicts arise in the bin/obj folders in some Class Libraries when I do updates, since I will rebuild the dll's anyway. I just don't know how to make SVN happy and tell it to ignore the conflicts - I would like to make a 'global' ignore so I will not have to do ignore every single time I update, but help in doing a simple ignore would be helpful as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Why are the generated components under source control in the first place?

The easier (and probably more proper) thing to do would be to remove the generated objects from source control.

Comment: okay. would i just choose the option 'Unversion and add to ignore list' then?