# SVN (or perhaps tortoiseSVN?) property to ignore local changes/conflicts and always overwrite on an update?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have seen variations on this question on stackoverflow, but never a definitive answer as most of them just tell people to change the workflow.

Yes, I know how SVN works and how to ignore files on a commit, but is there any way to actually ignore conflicts (i.e., a direct answer to [How to ignore conflicts in tortoiseSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271954/how-to-ignore-conflicts-in-tortoisesvn)) ?

Here is the workflow:

1. I have several coauthors working on a latex file, some are compiling to a PDF and others are just reading the compiled document.
2. Some will never compile the file directly (in fact, will not even have latex setup!), but want to get access to the latest copy of the compiled PDF.
3. I don't really care if the PDF gets a little out of date with the commits when being actively worked on, but I still want to be able to tell the coauthor who isn't compiling the paper to access the latest commited copy.
4. For those who are editing the latex file, some are not very technical and constant source of SVN conflicts when doing an update on the server is annoying and confusing.

Is there anyway to put in a property in SVN to ignore local changes and overwrite the local changes?  Since the less technical users would be using tortoiseSVN, it is fine if the solution is specific to that product.  Of course, I only would want to associate this with particular files.

**EDIT**
Since I can deal with a TortoiseSVN specific answer, is there a way to do this with TortoiseSVN hook scripts?  Maybe a pre-update hook to delete all .pdf files which have local changes?  Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Comment: I'm confused. I'd give the users who will never compile read-only access (they can basically just retrieve the latest) and everyone else gets checkout rights.

Comment: It is a little hard to explain without discussing latex, but the issue is the compiled binary gets local modifications, but there may be no changes in the underlying source file.  If someone wants to update the latest from the server, they hit conflicts on the compiled files, but it is an annoyance as they do not care if there is a conflict.  If I just ignore the binary files, then I can't have people look at the current binaries without compiling.

Comment: Basically: trust me that better workflows would be worse than the current workaround (i.e., tell people to manually revert local pdf files prior to any update, even if they are not all that technical and are confused).

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would use a CI tool like jenkins to auto-build the PDFs after each commit, and then automagically upload to a place where you can point the non-techies to.

No unnecessary svn conflicts to resolve, and everbody can see the new files about 5-10 minutes after a commit.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Alas, way too complicated for the people editing the files (who aren't especially techie themselves).  Things would be perfect if I just didn't have to worry about those commits.  Are there no workarounds?

Comment: Your solution with pdf in svn is worse, since somebody has to manually  generate and commit the PDF. With the jenkins you could just tell the lusers to go to `http:// jenkins.example.com/latest/foo.pdf`.

Comment: I want them to manually update the pdf, and not have anything change unless they update it on purpose.

Comment: That won't happen with your SVN solution either. The pdf would be over-written on any `svn update` - which you need to do often or you loose the ability to commit.

Comment: Exactly.  If it is not modified, I want them to manually be able to update and get the latest copy to examine (and not have to recompile, as they may not even have latex setup).  When they (or others) are editing the files, the only problem is that to do an update on the sourcefile and merge/etc. you may have local changes to your generated binary.  But they are irrelevant, and manually reverting is a pain in the ass.